# Existence of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$

How can one show that there exist function $f:[0,1]\times D \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfying the following properties:

(i) $f(\cdot,z)$ is continous on $[0,1]$ for every $z\in D$

(ii) $f(t,\cdot)$ is holomorphic on $D$ for every $t\in[0,1]$

(iii) $f$ is not continous on $[0,1]\times D$

?

I know that if exist $f$ satisfying (i) and (ii) then $f$ must be Borel function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Using Runge's theorem, for each positive integer $n$ there is a polynomial $P_n$ such that $|P_n(z)| < 1/n$ for $z \in D$ with $\text{Re}(z) \le 0$ or 
$\text{Re}(z) \ge 2/n$, but $|P_n(1/n) - 1| < 1/n$.  Let $f(1/n, z) = P_n(z)$ and ...